# Why is AWS Java SDK returning a Role is Invalid; Status Code 400 ValidationError?

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-ecs, aws-java-sdk

I have a Java Spring Boot app deployed in ECS in a private subnet, and I'm using `STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider` from the AWS Java SDK, which is a role-based authorization mechanism for my AWS SNS Client, and I'm getting this non-descriptive error.

```
com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.AWSSecurityTokenServiceException:
 aws:iam::XXXXXXXX:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole is invalid (Service: 
AWSSecurityTokenService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; 
Request ID: XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX; Proxy: null)
```

`ecsTaskExecutionRole` has `AdministratorAccess` policy attached to it (just for debugging purposes).

Code:

```
 STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider stsAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider = new STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider
                    .Builder(roleArn, "session").build();
```

Why am I getting this error, and how do I fix it?

note: I also tried using programmatic credentials from a user I created and received a similar error.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Turns out I copied the role arn wrong. I had

`roleArn: "aws:iam::999999999999:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole"`

instead of

`roleArn: "arn:aws:iam::999999999999:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole"`